# Authentication Error for ABBY Ocr Sdk!

Tags: apex, sdk

Getting error: Auth String must be valid base64 format...Posting the code...Kindly Help!

```
String url = 'http://cloud.ocrsdk.com/processImage?language=english&exportformat=pdfSearchable';

String appId='';
String pwd='';
String toEncode=appId+':' + pwd;
Blob beforeblob = Blob.valueOf(toEncode);
string paramvalue = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(beforeblob);
Attachment att = new Attachment();
att = [SELECT ID,Body,ContentType FROM Attachment where ContentType='image/jpeg' and ID='00P2800000KuwQf' LIMIT 1];
String strImg=EncodingUtil.base64Encode(att.body);
Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

        req.setEndpoint(url);
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader( 'Authorization', 'Basic' + paramvalue);
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
        req.setBody(imgBlob);
        req.setBody(strImg);        
        req.setHeader('Content-Length', String.valueOf(strImg.length()));
        HTTPResponse res = h.send(req);
        System.debug(res.getBody());
```

Comment: May not be the cause of this error, but you need a space after the word Basic i.e. `'Basic ' + paramvalue`.

Comment: Getting this error now...Unsupported image file format. Api supports a jpeg image and attachment contains a jpeg file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me using ABBY:

```
String encodedUrl = EncodingUtil.urlDecode(url, 'UTF-8');
String toEncode = appId + ':' + pwd;
String encoded = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(toEncode, 'iso-8859-1');

String key = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(toEncode));

HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint(encodedUrl);
request.setMethod('POST');
request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + key);

Attachment file = [Select Body, Name, ContentType, bodyLength  From Attachment Where ParentId = :this.scannedImage.Id And Name != 'description.xml' LIMIT 1];       
request.setHeader('Content-Type', file.ContentType);
request.setHeader('Content-Length', '' + file.bodyLength );
request.setBodyAsBlob(file.Body);
```